# Register BroadcastReceiver For Incoming SMS

Tags: android, sms, block

How to Register BroadcastReceiver For  blocking Incoming SMSs

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent."what should be here");
     ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following :

```
intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You should check for the permission

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 0);
} else {
        // register sms receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    } else {
        // register sms receiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
}
    }
```

Comment: what about READ_SMS i hope that is also required plus it's protection level is dangerous too

Answer (score 2):

Register a receiver in your manifest with highest priority:

```
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="9999"> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Create BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

Implement onReceive method:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("pdus")) {
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
    String senderNumber = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
    if( senderIsInBlackList(senderNumber)) {
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't priority supposed to be 0? According to google blog 0 means "run after all the others"

Comment: He/She wants to block some incoming messages, so this app should have highest available priority.

Comment: @Ali Behzadian Nejad The Google administrators for the Google Play Store consider the RECEIVE_SMS permission (in the tutorial you mention) to be dangerous. As a result, an app that contains the permission will be rejected. Then the developer has to submit a form to Google Play administrators for approval. Other developers have mentioned the process is awful with feedback taking weeks and receiving outright rejections with either no explanations or generic feedback. Any ideas on how to avoid?

Answer (score 1):

Declare the receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.example.YourSmsReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Hope this helps, Yaron