# Detect if incoming message has Keyword

Tags: android

I am developing an Android Application in which I want to check every incoming message on the device in order to detect if any incoming message contains my *Keyword*. I want this to be done in background (even if application is not running). Please tell how can I do that?

Comment: Create a service to read incoming message and perform requisite task.

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail can you please give a simple example in answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637821/how-to-analyze-incoming-sms-on-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587013/how-to-receive-incoming-sms-on-android-kitkat-or-above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306150/read-and-display-incoming-message-text-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911670/register-broadcastreceiver-for-incoming-sms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435354/receiving-sms-on-android-app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995244/

Answer (score 0):

Use a BroadcastReceiver to catch all incoming messages then send the message body to a Service to perform all your required task. Do not perform any long task in your BroadcastReceiver since it runs on the main thread.

Here is an example of how you can catch incoming SMS:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                // Send the message body to your custom service.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make changes in your Manifest to give your app the permissions to receive SMS (WRITE_SMS, READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS)
2. Create a broadcast receiver to process the received SMS intent from service

   ```
   private class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
   {    
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
       {
           Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();

           String message = "";

           if ( extras != null )
           {
               Object[] extras = (Object[]) intentExtras.get( "pdus" );

               for ( int i = 0; i < extras.length; i++ )
               {
                   SmsMessage smsmsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsextras[i]);

                   String message = smsmsg.getMessageBody().toString();
                   //process your message

                }

           }

       }
   ```

   }
3. Create a service class and register it to receive the android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED intent filter:

   public class SMSService extends Service
       {
           private SMSBroadcastReceiver SMSreceiver;
           private IntentFilter intentFilter;

   ```
       @Override
       public void onCreate()
       {
           super.onCreate();

           //SMS event receiver
           SMSreceiver = new SMSBroadcastReceiver();
           intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
           mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
           registerReceiver(SMSreceiver, intentFilter);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDestroy()
       {
           super.onDestroy();
           unregisterReceiver(mSMSreceiver);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The Google administrators for the Google Play Store consider the RECEIVE_SMS permission (in the tutorial you mention) to be dangerous. As a result, an app that contains the permission will be rejected. Then the developer has to submit a form to Google Play administrators for approval. Other developers have mentioned the process is awful with feedback taking weeks and receiving outright rejections with either no explanations or generic feedback. Any ideas on how to avoid?